# Как вытащить минимальное и максимальное значение из многомерного объекта js?

Tags: javascript

```
obj={
    a0:{aa:[3,9], bb:2, cc:{aaa:4,bbb:-5}},
    a1:{aa:[0,8], bb:-7, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:7}},
    a2:{aa:[9,-4], bb:1, cc:{aaa:-1,bbb:8}},
    a3:{aa:[8,-1], bb:7, cc:{aaa:3,bbb:0}},
    a4:{aa:[-4,-2], bb:-2, cc:{aaa:8,bbb:9}}
}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, каким должен быть результат в данном случае? Поиск по всем ключам и внутри массивов тоже?

Comment: Да, по всем ключам.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно точно ответить на этот вопрос. Сильно зависит от того, по какому именно ключу мы ищем значения.

Однако в случае, если мы ищем по ключу **bb**, скрипт может выглядеть так

```
Math.max(...Object.values(obj).map(elem=>elem.bb))
```

- Здесь с помощью метода values мы получаем из объекта значения.
- Метод map позволяет нам создать на основе массива из объектов массив из чисел (достав значения по ключу).
- Метод max объекта Math помогает нам найти максимально значения из множества аргументов. Для этого мы распаковываем ранее полученный список оператором **...**